# How to read from mysql datetime field

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to read from mysql field with datetime type and I was trying everything and always it's return field name only.

Here is my code:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string query = @"SELECT `sID`, 'sDate', `sGameLogin`, `dGameAmount`, 
                    'sPayMethod' FROM `XeronRequests` WHERE `iStatus` = 0";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {                    
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(new PaymentInfoText(dataReader["sID"] + "", 
                     dataReader["sDate"] + "", 
                     dataReader["sGameLogin"] + "", 
                     dataReader["dGameAmount"] + "", 
                     dataReader["sPayMethod"] + ""));
        }
    }

    e.Result = list;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all those backticks? Surely you only need those for reserved words...

Comment: Backticks could be added automatically by some tool, or just typed per default. They do no harm.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
dataReader.GetDateTime(dataReader.GetOrdinal("sDate"))
```

instead of

```
dataReader["sDate"] + ""
```

and remove the ticks around your columns in the sql, e.g.

`sDate` instead of `'sDate'`. You need them only for reserved words or if you have spaces in your column names:

[9.3. Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

[2.2. Reserved Words in MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `SELECT` statement, you have single quotes `'` instead of back ticks around `sDate` and so the value of that field is in fact `"sDate"`.

Or as Jon Skeet stated, get rid of the back ticks entirely because they exist for keywords only, must like the `[]` do for MSSQL.